# Find files with specific character in second position in name

Tags: find, regular-expression, wildcards

How can I find files with this pattern like `??11*` or `??52*`, start with two unknown numbers and two specific numbers and other nothing matter.

```bsh
972966220_56_2_1_L2_P.jpg       971051472_69_2_1_L2_P.jpg
311952411_45_2_1_L2_P.jpg       150221433_0_2_1_L2_P.jpg
363117383_0_2_1_L2_P.jpg        190638610_78_2_1_L2_P.jpg
752944572_42_2_1_L2_P.jpg       253138391_61_2_2_L2_P.jpg
841542999_33_1_1_L1_P.jpg       911539144_72_2_1_L2_P.jpg
741545726_38_2_1_L2_P.jpg       143145435_70_2_1_L2_P.jpg
742956510_40_2_1_L2_P.jpg       683275391_42_2_2_L2_P.jpg
773278422_0_2_1_L2_P.jpg        732877320_69_2_2_L2_P.jpg
562472955_48_2_1_L2_P.jpg       871074372_81_2_1_L2_P.jpg
582113611_18_2_2_L2_P.jpg       351728725_61_2_1_L2_P.jpg
662989573_0_2_1_L2_P.jpg        482146746_26_2_2_L2_P.jpg
140657988_48_2_1_L2_P.jpg       571769896_56_2_2_L2_P.jpg
142414844_33_2_1_L2_P.jpg       641513381_72_2_1_L2_P226.jpg
571769896_0_2_1_L2_P.jpg        231514166_60_2_1_L2_P.jpg
653099122_37_2_1_L2_P.jpg       370649838_41_2_2_L2_P.jpg
712937376_34_2_1_L2_P.jpg       790498538_64_2_1_L2_P.jpg
193178710_35_2_1_L2_P.jpg       792887777_106_2_1_L2_P.jpg
611926710_49_2_1_L2_P.jpg       280234330_70_2_1_L2_P.jpg
613034344_44_2_1_L2_P.jpg       461587572_93_2_1_L2_P.jpg
```

Comment: does your `find` version offer the `-regex` test?

Comment: Unless I'm misreading something, none of your example files match either of your patterns. There are files with `?11*` or `?52*`, but none with `??11*` or `??52*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find -name` can work with `??11*` or `??52*`. It's not regex but it may be enough.

```
find . -name '??11*' -o -name '??52*'
```

Note `?` can match a non-digit. To match a digit use `[0123456789]`. The forms `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]` are useful in general but locale-dependent. I can see the filenames in question use `0123456789` for sure, so `[0123456789]` is the best choice. Examples:

```
find . -name '[0123456789][0123456789]11*' -o -name '[0123456789][0123456789]52*'
# or
LC_ALL=C find . -name '[0-9][0-9]11*' -o -name '[0-9][0-9]52*'
```

There is not a single match among the filenames you provided though.